# Ubuntu Gnome VS Fedora Gnome (Workstation)

Tags: unity, gnome, steam, fedora

I am a new Linux user. I installed Ubuntu with Gnome desktop environment (I really do not like the Unity shell, looks so bad in my opinion).

I like very much the Gnome, it looks more pro. I installed Ubuntu and not Fedora because, from what I have read, it is more popular and runs on tablets and phones (I hope there will be a Gnome option at installation, like OpenSuse has).

Anyway, what is the difference between running the same Gnome desktop environment in Ubuntu and Fedora?

What happens of one day Ubuntu will no longer support Gnome? Ubuntu Gnome is powered by "the community", that is how they say on forums, but what community? The Canonical/Ubuntu community or a general Linux community?

Comment: TL;DR: None for BFU. But `gnome-shell` is tested on Fedora because it is default. Ubuntu is more focused to their *Unity* so everything might not work as expected. But your chrome, music and stuff should work the same.

Comment: This is super-biased (disclaimer: as am I personally) because it comes from one of the developers of Fedora Workstation: [Fedora Workstation: More than the sum of its parts](https://blogs.gnome.org/uraeus/2015/04/20/fedora-workstation-more-than-the-sum-of-its-parts/) Quote: _"So when you look at the user experience you get on Fedora Workstation, remember that it is not just a question of which version of GNOME we are shipping, but it is the fact that we are working hard on putting together a tightly vertically integrated and tested system from the kernel up to core desktop applications."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences will be extremely subtle.

Ubuntu, before the 11.04 release, used the GNOME shell. But it kept alive after Unity's release with Ubuntu GNOME.

The GNOME shell used by Ubuntu is basically the same used by Fedora. The things that may change are the shell's version and the default theme used on it.

The GNOME project is one of the oldest initiatives to bring a full desktop experience. There was a time when a Linux user had to choose between KDE and GNOME. There weren't other relevant DEs at all. Ubuntu still uses lots of GNOME applications and resources, and the project is rock solid. So it probably won't be abandoned (not in a near future).

The same happens with Ubuntu GNOME: just like you, there are tons of people who dislike Unity or simply prefer to use other Desktop Environments. And while Ubuntu and GNOME keep being popular, Ubuntu GNOME will prosper. By the way, it is maintained by a separate community; Canonical does not develop it, but instead gives official support to the project.

Comment: Eduardo Cola: so if I have installed ubuntu gnome 15.10, which comes with gnome 3.16 integrated, is a bad ideea to upgrade gnome to 3.18?  I allready did it because gnome 3.18 has GOOGLE DRIVE integrated with online accounts. Will this change do something bad?

Comment: No problem if you do everything the correct way (adding trusty PPAs, installing with APT, etc.). But Ubuntu 16.04 is on its way (less than 3 months to come out), and it will come with GNOME 3.19. You may want to remove your old PPAs and upgrade to the new version, since GNOME 3.19 will be in its official repositories.

Comment: Is there any way of update that will remove automatically the things that u have just said? When I did the update I just added 3 lines of code (from an official website) in the terminal and that was it. So will be any different? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if the software updater removes third party PPAs. But to make sure, it's better to remove them. If you don't know how to do it, please consider making a system backup and doing a fresh reinstall. It's failsafe in these cases.